# Iterating an ArcGIS tool over multiple Fields with selection boxes

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have one shapefile that contains many fields and I'd like to write a simple script tool that allows me to run IDW for the fields I select. Is this possible?

For example.....

**Input**: 1 shapefile

```
Sample  field1  field2  field3  field4 .....
1       26.5    27.5    22.2    32.3  
2       19.1    12.2    45.3    33.3 
3       11.1    15.6    44.4    34.4
```

**Options**:

field 1 ☑

field 2 ☑

field 3 ☑
.....

**Output**: field1_IDW, field2_IDW, field3_IDW .....

EDIT: The following code works properly

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inPointFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fieldList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Define local variables
cellSize = 250.0
power = 2
searchRadius = RadiusVariable(12)

for fieldName in fieldList.split(';'):
    outIDW = Idw(inPointFeatures, fieldName, cellSize, power, searchRadius)
    # Save the output 
    outIDW.save("C:/temp/idwout_{0}.tif".format(fieldName))
```

Comment: ESRI has a blog about the subject here:http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/25/generating-a-choice-list-from-a-field/

Comment: This subject refers to a model where you can select multiple values within a field, I believe. I'm trying to select multiple fields. Can the logic here be used to achieve that goal, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, here is the general code logic:

1. Create a script tool with a Field multi value data type
2. Within the python code, loop through the field list and define the index value as the field parameter within the IDW method

   ```
   fieldList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
   for fieldName in fieldList.split(';'):
       outIDW = Idw(inPointFeatures, fieldName, cellSize, power, searchRadius)
       # Save the output 
       outIDW.save("C:/temp/idwout_{0}.tif".format(fieldName))
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! Is there a way to automatically populate the field names in the data type or do they have to be entered manually? I'm editing my post with a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, you need to source the field data type to be obtained from parameter to the feature class within the script tool parameters tab.

Comment: Thanks again. I now see a list of fields associated with my shapefile, but I am getting an error. Do you see a problem with my code (posted above)? I'm getting this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (script.py, line 2)

Comment: Can you add your error message to your question?

Comment: Sorry - added. Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (script.py, line 2)

Comment: I made a foolish error before - fixed. I'm getting a new error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\script\script.py", line 18, in <module>
    outIDW = Idw(shapefile, fieldName, "442.452", "2", "VARIABLE 12")
NameError: name 'Idw' is not defined

Comment: You may not be checking out the extension, looks like the word spatial needs to be proper case, e.g. "Spatial".

Comment: Your advice was fruitful and the script now works properly. I updated the code in my initial post.